# If car starts and cuts out after 10 seconds, does that mean its definitely not related to CCA?

Tags: battery

If a car starts, I assume it means there is enough cold cranking amps to start the car.  Therefore if it cuts out after a few, 10, or even 30 seconds, it means the cut out problem is definitely not related to your battery's CCA.  I just want to check that my assumption is correct.

Comment: You've received a comprehensive answer from Fred_dot_u to the question you asked. Asking a new question regarding which other systems to suspect would be a proper next step.

Comment: @psaxton he seems to be implying less then 10 seconds maybe a problem and I did mention a 'few seconds' in my question too.  Unless I am interpreting his answer incorrectly and he is saying an immediate cut out after a start means no cca or starter problems.

Comment: @JamesWilson if the starter is able to turn the motor the battery is fine.  Also CCA is about performance in extreme temperature conditions, it is mid March so unless you are in a polar region you probably are not operating in extreme cold.

Comment: A separate question helps future internet people to find and resolve their problems as well.

Answer (score 8):

If your engine turns over fast enough with the systems operational in a manner sufficient to start the engine, even if the engine is running only 10-30 seconds, and you've released the key from the start position, the battery/starter circuit is out of the picture.

Your assumption is correct.

Comment: what about less then 10 seconds, and if its a problem why?

Comment: @JamesWilson: It takes a few cycles for some alternators to start working. I've actually had my truck stall because I let go of the starter too fast.

Comment: When the engine dies immediately after releasing the starter the first suspect is the ignition resistor.

Comment: I have gone on to find that while a starting car should mean the cca is ok, cutting out doesn’t mean the battery and starter circuit is ok.  In this case, the cut out was caused by corroded battery terminals.